# How to mask a url in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

In mvc how to make a URL like this:
www.example.com/SomethingElse
go to a controller named for example "UsersList" -> which should be www.example.com/List

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MyRoute",
    "List",
    new { controller = "UsersList", action = "Index" }
);
```

Now when you navigate to `/list`, the `Index` action of the `UsersList` controller will be executed.

Comment: I did that, but it tell me that:The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /List

Comment: @AmrElGarhy, maybe you have some other routes defined which are conflicting with it? Can you show your entire route definition?

Comment: it worked, it just need to appear before the default route, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Amr: I think you are looking at the routing framework.  In a standard asp.net Mvc application, there is an area in the global ASAx file that you can define routes, much like you are talking about.

Comment: create a default mvc project and take a look @ the global.asax.  that should get you started honestly.